# Cannot read property '_syncPendingControls' of undefined in angular

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I am trying to upload two files in one form using reactive form. When I tried to upload in different forms, I am not getting any error, however now as soon as the page uploads, I get an error:

```
  ERROR Error: formGroup expects a FormGroup instance. Please pass one in.

           Example:


        <div [formGroup]="myGroup">
          <input formControlName="firstName">
        </div>

        In your class:

        this.myGroup = new FormGroup({
           firstName: new FormControl()
        });
```

And after uploading two files in a form (where the form is inside a modal page) and clicking on submit button, I get an error -

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '_syncPendingControls' of
>   undefined

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="ngxSmartModalService.getModal('mySourceNTargetModal').open()" style="visibility:hidden" id="mySourceNTargetModal">Open myModal</button>

<ngx-smart-modal #myTargetModal identifier="mySourceNTargetModal">
  <form (ngSubmit)="sourceNTargetModalButton(addSourceNTargetModalData.value);mySourceNTargetModal.close()" [formGroup]="addTargetModalData">
    <!-- <label style="font-size: 1.2em !important;
     font-weight: 500 !important;"> Enter Details:</label> -->
    <!-- <hr> -->
<div  class = "sourceNTargetContainer">


    <div class="form-group row">
        <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" style="font-size: 1.2em !important;
        font-weight: 500 !important;">Select Source file</label>
        <div class="col-sm-13">
            <input id="cin" type="file"  (change)="fileTargetChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload Source file" [formControl]="addSourceNTargetModalData.controls['addSourceFile']" multiple/>
            <!-- <p style="color: rgb(223, 55, 55);; font-size:15px"
            *ngIf="addSourceNTargetModalData.get('addSourceFile').hasError('required') && addSourceNTargetModalData.get('addSourceFile').touched"> -->

          </div>
      </div>

      <br>
      <hr>
      <br>

    <div class="form-group row">
      <label class="col-sm-3 col-form-label" style="font-size: 1.2em !important;
      font-weight: 500 !important;">Select Target file</label>
      <div class="col-sm-13">
          <input id="cin" type="file"  (change)="fileTargetChangeEvent($event)" placeholder="Upload Target file" [formControl]="addSourceNTargetModalData.controls['addTargetFile']" multiple/>
          <!-- <p style="color: rgb(223, 55, 55);; font-size:15px"
          *ngIf="addSourceNTargetModalData.get('addTargetFile').hasError('required') && addSourceNTargetModalData.get('addTargetFile').touched"> -->

        </div>
    </div>


    <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-secondary"  >
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-icon-shield"></i>&nbsp;Submit</button>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
  </form>
</ngx-smart-modal>
```

How can I solve the error?

Comment: Have you created a new instance of FormGroup in you TS file as the error mentions?

Comment: yes. I have added it. It is because probably, i am unable to define it in form-control validators.